# How to find the list of 'paths' on my site?

Tags: uri

I recently became the administrator of a Drupal site. I am attempting to configure various blocks on the page, and have so far only succeeded in removing them altogether. The configuration menu tells me to enter the 'path' for where I want the block to appear. How do I find the list of path names available for entry? The site has a blog, but entering "blog" or even "blog/*" did not make the block appear on the block.

Answer (score 8):

To get all the paths you can use, you can use the following code to get all the paths defined from modules:

```
$items = module_invoke_all('menu');
drupal_alter('menu', $items);
foreach ($items as $path => $info) {
  print preg_replace('/%([a-z0-9_]*)/i', '*', $path);
}
```

The code will show the path as you enter in the block settings; this means it will change `node/%node` in `node/*`, and `node/%node/edit` in `node/*/edit`.

About your specific issue, the block could not appear because the block has not been assigned to any theme section, the theme doesn't define the section where the block should appear, or the block is empty. In most cases, modules don't output empty blocks.

Comment: this listing will find paths defined by modules, where `/admin/config/search/path` will only show content aliases.

Comment: You can put the code above on a file, for example `get-paths.php`, and then execute it like this: `drush php-script get-paths.php`

Comment: Wrap the `print` in an `if (!path_is_admin($path)) {` if you don't want admin paths.

Comment: ```$items = module_invoke_all('menu');
drupal_alter('menu', $items);
foreach ($items as $path => $info) {
  if (!path_is_admin($path)) {
    print preg_replace('/%([a-z0-9_]*)/i', '*', $path) . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hrm, this doesn't actually show all the aliases registered.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Path module (core) enabled, there will be a page that lists all URL aliases on the site.

If using Drupal 7: example.com/admin/config/search/path

If using Drupal 6: example.com/admin/build/path

Comment: While helpful, this isn't sufficient, there are others ways to register paths in Drupal that the Path module doesn't display. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/14586/6602 has a more robust solution.